# Fetch params from search React js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How to fetch *params* from

```
props.location.search
```

where i tried

```
const { propKey, propEid } =  new URLSearchParams(props.location.search);
```

but `propKey` and  `propEid` shows unidentified  in `console.log`

my url is like so:

> {{baseurl}}/verify-email?key=a6d16a22a82f16c96ee7d2f95c45c9bc&eid=c2Frc2hpMTFAZ21haWwuY29t

Comment: sample of `props.location.search` & why are u destructuring `URLSearchParams` ?

Comment: You have to use [`.get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get) to get values from `URLSearchParams`.

Comment: @aXuser264 coz my url has two params in query, updated above

Comment: @Agney according to my problem above, can you please explain how to get the values of params? something like this? URLSearchParams.get(name)

Comment: @Sakshi doesn't matter, `URLSearchParams` can handle that (as *Agney* pointed out) checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search);
const key = params.get('key'); // a6d16a22a82f16c96ee7d2f95c45c9bc&eid=c2Frc2hpMTFAZ21haWwuY29t
```